# Residual Neural Network with 2D input data in tensorflow

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I have a simple feedforward network to approximate a function $f(x,y)$. I'm interested in adding skip-connections to my network (i.e. ResNet). In 1D, it's fairly straightforward. Here's a code snippet for a single block:

```
def create_model(X, weights, biases, num_layers, num_hidden):

    # first layer
    W = weights[0]
    b = biases[0]
    H = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W), b))

    # interior hidden layers
    for l in range(1,num_layers-2):
        W = weights[l]
        b = biases[l]
        H = tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(H, W), b))

    # residual connection 
    W = weights[num_layers-2]
    b = biases[num_layers-2]
    H = tf.add(tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(H, W), b)), X)

    # output (activation) layer, linear
    W = weights[-1]
    b = biases[-1]
    Y = tf.add(tf.matmul(H, W), b)

    return Y
```

The above code snippet runs due to broadcasting. In particular, we have
$$
\sigma(\sigma(\mathbf{x}W_{1} + b_{1})W_{2} + b_{2}) + \mathbf{x}
$$

for a block with two hidden layers and a skip connection. Let $n$ be the number of neurons and $W_{1} \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$, $W_{2} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $b_{1}, b_{2} \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n}$. Suppose $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}$ (so $m$ is the length of the input `X`). We have the first term $\sigma(\sigma(\mathbf{x}W_{1} + b_{1})W_{2} + b_{2})$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, and tensorflow allows broadcasting so that $\mathbf{x}$ is added to each column of the first term. Is this how the skip connection is supposed to work?

I'm interested in extending this to two-dimensional functions, again only with a single block for now:

```
# initialize weights
def initialize_NN(num_layers, num_hidden):    
    weights = []
    biases = []

    # first layer, based on input data
    W = init_weights([2, num_hidden], 'xavier', xavier_params=(1, num_hidden))
    b = init_weights([1, num_hidden], 'zeros')
    weights.append(W)
    biases.append(b)  

    # interior hidden layers
    for l in range(1,num_layers-1):
        W = init_weights([num_hidden, num_hidden], 'xavier', xavier_params=(num_hidden, num_hidden))
        b = init_weights([1, num_hidden], 'zeros')
        weights.append(W)
        biases.append(b)  

    # output (activation) layer
    W = init_weights([num_hidden, 1], 'xavier', xavier_params=(num_hidden, 1))
    b = init_weights([1, 1], 'zeros')   
    weights.append(W)
    biases.append(b)  

    return weights, biases

# setup model
def create_model(X, Y, weights, biases, num_layers, num_hidden):

    DATA = tf.concat((X, Y), axis=1) 

    # first layer
    W = weights[0]
    b = biases[0]
    U = tf.nn.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(DATA, W), b))

    # interior hidden layers
    for l in range(1,num_layers-2):
        W = weights[l]
        b = biases[l]
        U = tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(U, W), b))

    # residual connection
    W = weights[num_layers-2]
    b = biases[num_layers-2]
    U = tf.add(tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(U, W), b)), DATA)

    # output (activation) layer, linear
    W = weights[-1]
    b = biases[-1]
    U = tf.add(tf.matmul(U, W), b)

    return U
```

Of course, I get an error with the shapes now since `DATA` is two-dimensional. The error I get is

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 100 and 2 for 'Add_3' (op: 'Add') with input shapes: [?,100], [?,2].
```

in this line:

```
U = tf.add(tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(U, W), b)), DATA)
```

I've read that I should multiply by some appropriate transformation $W_{s}$, but I'm not sure how to determine this mapping. If I tried something like

```
U = tf.add(tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(U, W), b)), tf.matmul(DATA, tf.identity(weights[0]))))
```

then it certainly fixes the shape issue, but I'm not sure if this is correct. Can someone explain to me or suggest a good tutorial how I can rectify this problem?